# How can i use void ContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) method in our application?

Tags: iphone, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, box2d-iphone

I dont know how to use this metnod in my application

```
void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {

    b2WorldManifold worldManifold;

    contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold);

    b2PointState state1[2], state2[2];

    b2GetPointStates(state1, state2, oldManifold, contact->GetManifold());
    //NSLog(@"Presolving");

    if (state2[0] == b2_addState)
    {
        const b2Body* bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();

        const b2Body* bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

        b2Vec2 point = worldManifold.points[0];

        b2Vec2 vA = bodyA->GetLinearVelocityFromWorldPoint(point);

        b2Vec2 vB = bodyB->GetLinearVelocityFromWorldPoint(point);

        b2Vec2 rV = vB - vA;

        float32 approachVelocity = b2Dot(rV, worldManifold.normal);

        if (-1.5f < approachVelocity && approachVelocity < 0.0f)       
        {

            //MyPlayCollisionSound();
            NSLog(@"Not Playing Sound");

        }
        else 
        {
            NSLog(@"playing the sound");

        }

    }

}
```

How can I use this code in my HelloWorldLayer.mm Please help me...
I have a problem here, I have a scene where some bodies falls and hit a static body, edges alike, I implemented the b2ContactListener, and in my tick method Im checking for contacts and play the sound, the problem with this approach is that when a body is constantly in contact with the static body, the sound plays indefinitely overlaying the previous one, so at the end I have huge noise..
What can I do to avoid this situation?

Please help me thanks......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used following method into your update method and declare its object before schedule update method call.
Like in HelloWorldLayer.h

```
MyContactListener *contactListener;
```

And in HelloworldLayer.mm

Before

```
[self scheduleupdate];

contactListener=new MyContactListener();
world->setContactListener(contactListener);
```

Than this type of error not occur.

Answer (score 0):

When two bodies collide, the `b2ContactListener` methods are called in the following sequence:

```
BeginContact

PreSolve
PostSolve
PreSolve
PostSolve
...etc

EndContact
```

So if you want to detect collision between the bodies once for each collision, use `BeginContact` or `EndContact` instead. These methods only take a single `b2Contact` parameter though so you might need to do away with using the `oldManifold` value in your calculation.